# How to verify account termination with user's password in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I built the authentication system for my Rails application from scratch following [this tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch) (among others).

Everything works as intended but it is still too easy for a user to destroy his own account (and thus all the data it contains):

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Your account has been deleted."
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

Right now, I have this in my `edit` view:

```
<%= link_to "Delete own account", @user, :confirm => "Are you REALLY sure?", :method => :delete %>
```

What is the *Rails way* to extend this and require the user's password as well before s/he can destroy their own account?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add some logic for that.

Follow this:

1. **Create a form** *using [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)) on `destroy`/(whichever page you want to), asking the password of the signed in user. **Route** the form to some action.
2. In the sent **action**, **authenticate** the user against the password supplied; if it matches, call `@user.destroy`, otherwise, `flash` the error and warning etc.

Comment: OK, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I got stuck again, though, and posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492488/how-to-post-to-destroy-action-with-form-for-in-rails-app).