# How to post to destroy action with form_for in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails app I want my `users` to enter their password before destroying their own account.

So in my **routes.rb** I added this to my `user` resource:

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :terminate
  end
end
```

In my **terminate.html.erb** I have this simple form:

```
<%= form_for(:user, :controller => "users", :action => "destroy", :html => {:method => "delete"}) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :password %><br/>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.submit "Terminate account" %><br/>

<% end %>
```

In my **users_controller.rb** I have this:

```
def terminate
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @title = "Terminate your account"
end

def destroy

  # make sure entered password is correct etc...

  @user.destroy
  flash[:success] = "Your account was terminated."
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

However, when I click submit I get this error:

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/en/users/7/terminate"
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%= form_for @user, method: :delete do |f| %>
```